# Wordcloud showing image but not words in R

Tags: r, word-cloud, wordcloud2

Having trouble getting the words to show up on an image mask for a word cloud in R.

Using this Simpsons PNG  (https://imgbin.com/png/PV5MuKbG/lisa-simpson-bart-simpson-homer-simpson-maggie-simpson-mayor-quimby-png)

Code is below:

```
wc1 <- sort(table(bplot_one$word), decreasing = TRUE)

figPath <- "Simpsons.png" 

wordcloud2(wc1, figPath = figPath)
```

It executed fine, but all I get is the png without the words

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is listed as an open issue on the package site: [Fig Mask and lettercloud are not working with package installed from github #68](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/68). There is a workaround posted: [mask and letterCloud silently fail #12](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12#).

The workaround is to refresh the viewer or open in a browser.